# Microsoft Excel Multiple Worksheets and Data

Tags: excel-formula

I have two spreadsheets built. I want to be able to put what step a teacher is in which looks like this; BS, 1 or BS, 2 etc. (My second worksheet has each step and salary on it) I then would like the cell directly next to it to pull the correct salary amount from my other Worksheet.

I would add a picture, however it won't let me. Thank you for any help you can offer me.

Comment: don't add a picture add the values as text.  Copy and paste them into the Original post.  Someone will help with the formatting.  With out that info it is hard to help with a formula, but what it sounds like you want VLOOKUP().

Comment: A better formatted example would help with possible answers.

Comment: Thank you, yes I used VLOOKUP. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of the teacher and category of the teacher is in Sheet1 columns A and B

```
(A)      |   (B)
         |   
Max      |    1
Tammy    |    4
Alex     |    2
```

and on Sheet 2 you have category and salary

```
(A)      |   (B)
         |    
1        |     30000
2        |     45000
3        |     75000
4        |    120000
```

Then in cell C1 on sheet 1 you would use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($B1,'Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
```

You would then copy this formula down as required.

Alternatively you could achieve the same results with an INDEX/MATCH combination

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$B$1:$B$4,MATCH(B1,'Sheet2'!$A1:$A$2),0)
```